# how to get given pixel values picture(image) in video frame

Tags: python-3.x

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

capture=cv.VideoCapture(r"E:/image processing/naturevideo.mp4")
frames=capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
print("number of frames:",frames)
fps = capture.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
print('frames per second =',fps)

success, image = capture.read()
count = 0
while success:
    count += 1
    print("{}th image from the naturevideo ".format(count))
    for x in range(0,1280-1):
           for y in range(0,720-1):
           v = image[y, x]
           print("Pixel at ({}, {}) - Value {} ".format(x,y,v))

    success, image = capture.read()
    capture.release()
```

1. 

| Column A | Column B |
| -------- | -------- |
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   |
| Cell 3   | Cell 4   |
cv.destroyAllWindows()

Comment: "E:/image processing/naturevideo.mp4" in this video file have 366 frames.but i need  given pixel values result(picture or image) only. please teach me